# Rewrite mysqli_fetch_all() to get the same result

Tags: php

Since the servers version is older than 5.3.0, I need to rewrite the following piece of function to do the same as it does now:

```
else {

    $res = mysqli_query($_con, "SELECT * FROM house");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_all($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    return $row; 
}
```

In html I call it like this:

```
$results = getResults();

foreach ($results as $value) {
    echo $value['Title']." / "; echo $value['Version'];
}
```

How can I call the results in my html the same way but with different function?

EDIT: I want to get all of the results from table "house" but without the use of function `mysqli_fetch_all()`

Comment: Can you rephrase the question to make it clearer? As I read it now I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'd rather update the server than rewrite code.

Comment: I want to get all of the results from table "house" but without the use of function `mysqli_fetch_all()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a simple loop that calls `mysql_fetch_array()` and collects all the rows in an array.

```
function mysqli_fetch_all($res, $mode) {
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, $mode)) {
        $array[] = $row;
    }
    return $array;
}
```